# Not able to import AndroidNativeUtil

Tags: codenameone

I am Not able to import "com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil" in my project.I have to implement Sim binding functionality using Native code.So in native code I am trying to import below classes

```
import com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil;

import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import android.content.Context;
```

but I am not able to import this classes.do I need to include any third party library?

I am getting below error

> .java:8: error: cannot find symbol
>
> TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService
>   (Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
>                     symbol:   method getSystemService(String)
>
> location: class MyNativeImpl

while excecuting below code

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager) getSystemService (Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
          String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

What is the solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the symbol that isn't found is `getSystemService` which is indeed not declared in that class. You need to use `AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().getSystemService(...)`

Comment: but I am not able to import "AndroidNativeUtil" class

Comment: In what way? The error you listed didn't include that. That's why we usually need the full error log to help.